# How many bytes does \n use in a file?

Tags: file, python-3.x

Why does both of them give me the same output: ['\n', '1345435 35tdgf\n', 'fggfsty tgds3st545'] ?

file 't1.txt':

```
testcheckfdgddhd  
1345435 35tdgf  
fggfsty tgds3st545
```

This code

```
 f=open("t1.txt","r+")
 f.seek(16)
 l=f.readlines()
 print(l)
```

and this code

```
f=open("t1.txt","r+")
f.seek(17)
l=f.readlines()
print(l)
```

Both give me the same output: `['\n', '1345435 35tdgf\n', 'fggfsty tgds3st545']`

Why is that?

Comment: A hex editor is useful for answering questions like this. I recommend HxD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, in text mode (as opposed to binary mode `'r+b'`), \n is written as \r\n and \r\n read as \n. You happen to be seeking to the \r in one case and the following \n in the other.

Switch to binary mode to see the difference.